# Php array sum values with same key and send it to last row of php table in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have this table :
[image]

I want the last row Total: to display the sum of parcial values of all the users with the same name, for instance: debora fernandes global value should be 85€  (50 + 35)

im getting the values from database into an array like :

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => Debora Fernandes [2] => 01/12/2015 [3] => Eventos Sagres em Lisboa [4] => 13h as 18h [5] =>levou botas
[6] => deb [7] => 50€ [8] => 10 [9] => 5 [10] => 6333 )
```

but i cant select users with same name and then sum the parcial values , can any one give me a hand ?

heres my code :

```
<?php
  $strSQL = "select * from bruno_wallet  "; 

  // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
  $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

  // Loop the recordset $rs
  // Each row will be made into an array ($row1) using mysql_fetch_array
  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

$events = array_unique($row1);


echo '<table id="wallet_table1" width="900px" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">';

$nam=$events[0];
 ?><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
 <?php

echo "<td>";echo "<div class='w_promotora_images'>"; echo($events[6]);echo "</td></div>";  //foto
echo "<td>";echo "<div class='w_promotora_images'>"; echo($events[2]);echo "</td></div>";  //data
echo "<td class=' tb1'>";echo($events[1]);echo "</td>";  //nome
echo "<td class=' tb1'>";echo($events[3]);echo "</td>";  //evento
echo "<td class=' tb1'>";echo($events[4]);echo "</td>"; //horario
echo "<td class=' tb1'>";echo($events[5]);echo "</td>"; //obs
echo "<td class=' tb1'>";echo($events[9]);echo "</td>";  //horas
echo "<td class=' tb1'>";echo($events[8]);echo "</td>";  //valor hora
echo "<td class=' tb1'>";echo($events[0]);echo "</td>"; //Props
echo "</td>";echo "<td>"; //valor parcial e global
echo "parcial:";echo($events[7]);echo "<br>global: "; //here i need to figure out how to merge $events[7] to all the users with the same name 

echo "</td></tr>"; 

}?>
```

my sql tables look like this :
[image]

i want to sum  totalparcial of tables with the same name and display it (maybe i need to create a table with the total ?

Update of my tables with ID 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to loop over the records before outputing it and preparing another array.

```
<?php
$strSQL = "select * from bruno_wallet  "; 

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
// Each row will be made into an array ($row1) using mysql_fetch_array
$sum = 0;
$data = array();
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $events = array_unique($row1);
    $data[] = $events;
    $sum += $events[7];
}

//now loop over data instead of mysql_fetch_array
foreach ($data as $events) {
    echo '<table id="wallet_table1" width="900px" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">';

    $nam=$events[0];
    ?><tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <?php

    echo "<td>";
    echo "<div class='w_promotora_images'>{$events[6]}</td></div>";  //foto
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<div class='w_promotora_images'>{$events[2]}</td></div>";  //data
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[1]}</td>";  //nome
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[3]}</td>";  //evento
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[4]}</td>"; //horario
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[5]}</td>"; //obs
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[9]}</td>";  //horas
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[8]}</td>";  //valor hora
    echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[0]}</td>"; //Props
    echo "<td>{$sum}</td></tr>"; 
}?>
```

I also made use of php's ability to expand variables in double quoted strings.

Comment: i niek , i now get the total: 169 what i need for the total is  to sum $events[7] in all rows that have the same name $events[1]

Comment: The only issue with this solution is performance.  PHP is much slower at this than SQL is.  Also, if there is any paging happening now, or in the future, this will break, as you will either not have all of the rows, or you will exhaust execution memory.

Comment: i cant get this to work ...   if i do  $strSQL1  = "SELECT nome, SUM(totalparcial) as Soma FROM bruno_wallet GROUP BY nome";  i can do the sum but i cant pass it to the table :(

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt this in `SQL`, which would be fastest and likely easiest, a query like:

```
select *, SUM(same_nome.totalparcial) AS global from bruno_wallet INNER JOIN bruno_wallet AS same_nome ON bruno_wallet.nome same_nome.nome GROUP BY bruno_wallet.id
```

Should do the trick.  You will have to find out the column name for `nome` (Name) and for the row ID, and for the row total (which I assumed was `parcial`).

I may be able to help if I know the column names, and may be able to give you a better idea.

The other option is to load all of the rows into memory and do the sum manually, but that gets complicated, large, and will be problematic if there is paging.

Comment: tks mike , i just updated my question with my sql db tables can u look at it ? i want to sum the parcial values of the users with the same name , maybe i need to create a row called total

Comment: I still do not see the ID column

Comment: do we need an id column ... the tables are getting filled dinamicly so the ids arent fixed...

Comment: An ID column, or compound key, is used to uniquely identify each row.  It would be needed in this case to group the joins by the parent ID/key so that we can cum the members of the group.

Comment: i updated my tables with an id  (edited my question with a picture) but have no clue how to do this.. can u helme mike ?

Comment: OK, that is what I expected then, that query should be all set?  No?

Comment: the query is invalid somehow when i runit on phpadmin :/ i get :Erro na consulta (1064): Syntax error near 'same_nome.nome GROUP BY bruno_wallet.id' at line 1

Comment: im using $strSQL = "SELECT *, SUM(totalparcial) as Soma FROM bruno_wallet GROUP BY nome ";  on php and i get the rows that repeat..with Soma field all ok but i still need to get the other rows that dosent repeat

Comment: You need the `JOIN` portion as well.  But if you do not feel comfortable using that, do two queries: This `sum` one, and the original.  And do a lookup on the `sum`'d array for the global total.